# Is it possible to remap /camera/color topics in realsense2_camera

Tags: ros, remap, ros-kinetic, realsense-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with a realsense camera ([relasense2_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/realsense2_camera) package), such that I need to remap the `/my_namespace/camera/color/*` topics to `/my_namespace/camera/rgb/*`. I have tried with a launch file as below:

```
<launch>
  <group ns="my_namespace">
    <remap from="/my_namespace/camera/color" to="/my_namespace/camera/rgb" />
    <remap from="/my_namespace/camera/depth/image_rect_raw" to="/my_namespace/camera/depth/image_rect" />
    <include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/rs_rgbd.launch">
        <arg name="namespace" value="camera"/>
        <arg name="rgb" value="rgb"/>
    </include>
  </group>

</launch>
```

Nevertheless, when launching the file and checking the rostopic list outuput, I noted those topic didn't change. Is it possible to remap them?

From my launch file, the second remap (`from="/my_namespace/camera/depth/image_rect_raw" to="/my_namespace/camera/depth/image_rect"`) works well.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306463/is-it-possible-to-remap-/camera/color-topics-in-realsense2_camera/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-23**:
Are you sure you actually have a topic /my_namespace/camera/color when doing rostopic list ? (and without the remapping obviously).

Also this (`<arg name="namespace" value="camera"/>`) shouldn't work since there are no arguments namespace defined in the launch file (unless you've modified it ?)

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2018-10-23**:
Hi, it is not actually just a topic but a set of topics. When I do `rostopic list`, the following topics appear (among others):

```
/my_namespace/camera/color/camera_info
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw/compressed
```

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2018-10-23**:
...

```
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth
/my_namespace/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
```

...

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2018-10-23**:
those are the topics I need to remap (`color` to `rgb`).
About the namespace argument @Delb is right, it seems I used a previous version. After an update it is `<arg name="camera" value="camera"/>` now.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-24**:
You can get rid of your first remap, you have to remap a topic but you can't for a set of topics. But you did well setting the arg `rgb` to `rgb`, its default value is `color` so I'm not sure why it's not affected correctly.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-24**:
Can you try to replace `<arg name="camera" value="camera"/>` by something like `<arg name="camera" value="other_camera"/>` just to see if you will actually get a set of topics like `/my_namespace/other_camera/` ?

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2018-10-25**:
Yes, I replaced camera argument to `other_camera`, and all topics changed

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-25**:
But you still have the `/color/` set of topics ? It's weird that when you change the arg camera it works but not with rgb, are you sure you have `<arg name="rgb" default="color" />` in your rs_`rgbd.launch` ? You can even change the default value directly to `rgb`.

**Comment by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on 2018-10-25**:
Yes, I still have the set of `/color` topics and the launch file has `<arg name="rgb" default="color" />`, but even if I do `<arg name="rgb" default="rgb" />` the topics keep as `/color`.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-26**:
So it's probably "hard coded" somewhere, I've found in `realsense2_camera/scripts/rs2_listener.py` l42 : `'topic': '/camera/color/image_raw'`. Can you try to see if modifying this to 'topic': '/camera/rgb/image_raw' change something ? (eventhough it's not recommended to change the source files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason it seems to be hardcoded in `base_realsense_node.cpp` on line `116` (as of 2.1.4)

```
    _stream_name[COLOR] = "color";
```

---

Originally posted by [Cdfghglz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32355/cdfghglz/) with karma: 16 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kivrakh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31606/kivrakh/) on 2019-07-01**:
Instead, you can directly use the remap statement by putting **just before** the node description in the launch file

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-06-23**:
@kivrakh May I know how to remap?

I tried in command line `color:=rgb` and also in launch file `<remap from="color" to="rgb" />`
But both ways don't work for me.

**Comment by [kivrakh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31606/kivrakh/) on 2020-06-23**:
put remap statement before the group namespace definition. I solved this issue like that.

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-06-23**:
@kivrakh I tried the following setup in my launch file but still didn't manage to solve it. Btw do you test the spencer package with D435 successfully?

```
  <remap from="color" to="rgb"/> 

  <include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/rs_rgbd.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="/spencer/sensors/rgbd_front_top"/>
    <arg name="tf_prefix" value="rgbd_front_top"/>
  </include>
```

**Comment by [kivrakh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31606/kivrakh/) on 2020-06-23**:
I could not find my packages to verify the exact solution. As far as I remember, try to remap in `rs_rgbd.launch`. If you still could not manage, use the hardcoded solution in `base_realsense_node.cpp`.

```
<remap from="color" to="rgb"/> 
<group ns="$(arg camera)">
<!-- Launch the camera device nodelet-->
<include file="$(find realsense2_camera)/launch/includes/nodelet.launch.xml">
```

Yes, I test spencer package with D435, it can be somehow painfull. Upper_body_detector uses message time synchronizer applied to the depth, camera_info and ground plane topics. Make sure you synchronize all these topics. Also upper_body_detector is tied to a fixed 640x480 resolution, you may need  scale your input image (1280x720) appropriately

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-06-23**:
@kivrakh, I have remapped successfully and however only have detection result but not tracking.

I have seen what you mentioned in the [issue](https://github.com/spencer-project/spencer_people_tracking/issues/51). I have checked all three topics and all is around 30hz. The resolution is set to 640x480 when I launch the rs_rgbd.launch so I assume that I no need to rescale the input image. Do you have any rosbag file that you record from D435 before? For me do to the testing and debugging.

Thanks for your help :)

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2020-06-24**:
@kivrakh Can I contact you in person? I have struggled for the package using D435 for few weeks and might need your help really. My email address is chunjye088@gmail.com

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2021-03-09**:
@BCJ did you finally make the upper body detector work with Intel Realsense D435? I am having same issues that you related. Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [BCJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/55777/bcj/) on 2021-03-09**:
@Alessandro Melino
Yes I run the package successfully. May I know what is your error? If the error is same as above, you can follow the solution that have been mentioned there.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2021-03-09**:
@BCJ my problem is that the upper body detector seems to not receive any image, I desribed the problem in this issue if you can check it: https://github.com/spencer-project/spencer_people_tracking/issues/91
Thanks for your quick answer.